# Can we expect infinite many primes $p$ equal to the start of $frac(\sqrt{p})$?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, decimal-expansion

The following routine searches for prime numbers $\ p\ $ equal to the beginning of the fractional part of the decimal expansion of $\ \sqrt{p}\ $ :

```
? forprime(p=1,4*10^9,s=length(digits(p));x=frac(sqrt(p));if(truncate(x*10^s)==p
,print1(p," ")))
5711 8053139
?
```

> - Can we expect infinite many primes with the given property ?
> - What is the next prime number with the given property ?

Comment: The first question is unlikely to get a solid answer.

Comment: You are supposed to understand $\lfloor \frac{10^s}{\sqrt{p}} \rfloor = p$ means $p^{3/2} = 10^s +O(\sqrt{p})$. So this is implied by most [prime gap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_gap#Upper_bounds) conjectures.

Comment: I do not expect a proof for finite or infinite many primes, a heuristic (like in the case of the Wieferich primes) would be utterly sufficient.

Comment: For now the answer is "we don't know" and "yes" if you replace $\sqrt{p}$ by $p^\theta$ for some $\theta > 0.525$.

Comment: Another downvote without any reason ...